# Duplicated processing of class hierarchies java

Tags: java

We have two similar hierarchies of classes sitting in two packages. The code is not ours, so we cannot change it.
We have to process these hierarchies in a certain way. So far we end up duplicating lots of code. For instance we have two methods:

> void process(pckg1.Client client){...}

and

> void process(pckg2.Client client){...}

The bodies of the methods are identical except for the signature. The amount of the duplication is significant, but would not probably justify complexity of reflection.
Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Do they implement the same interfaces? Otherwise, you can probably use an adapter pattern.

Comment: An adapter, which was proposed by Robin Khral, seems much more complicated than the duplicated code.

Comment: Given any lack example code or a decent description of the problem, this is about all you are going to get.

Comment: Have you considered using reflection? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful

Comment: Alex, I would disagree. You should always look to apply the DRY principle.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to wrap the shared methods of`pckg1.Client` and `pckg2.Client`:

```
public interface ClientWrapper {
    void sharedMethod();
}

public class Packg1ClientWrapper implements ClientWrapper {
     private final pckg1.Client client;
     public Pck2ClientWrapper(final pckg1.Client client) {
         this.client = client;
     }
     public void sharedMethod() {
         client.sharedMethod();
     }
}

public class Packg2ClientWrapper implements ClientWrapper {
     private final pckg2.Client client;
     public Pck2ClientWrapper(final pckg2.Client client) {
         this.client = client;
     }
     public void sharedMethod() {
         client.sharedMethod();
     }
}
```

Then you can use `ClientWrapper` in your methods and optionally provide utility methods that create the wrapper.

```
public void process(final pckg1.Client client) {
    process(new Pckg1ClientWrapper(client));
}

public void process(final ClientWrapper wrapper) {
     wrapper.sharedMethod();
}
```

This obviously only makes sense if there are few external class and a big amount of custom code dealing with these classes.

Comment: The objects and their properties are rarely used more than once. The straightforward code-duplicated version will be much smaller and simpler.

Comment: In your second code block, you should have process(new Pckg1ClientWrapper(client));

Comment: No worries Robin, nice answer!

Comment: @Alex Okay, then I don’t see a simple solution to avoid code redundancy, sorry.